# Switch image to full screen on ipad

Tags: ipad, uiimageview, uiimage, fullscreen, uigesturerecognizer

I have a lot of trouble to accomplish this task on an ipad : when double tape on an image switch this image to full screen and when double taping again come back to the original display, same thing using pinching. I'm using `UIGestureRecognizer` to try to do this. Thanks for your help.

> ```
> GesturesViewController.h
> ```

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GesturesViewController : UIViewController 
    <UIActionSheetDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

> ```
> GesturesViewController.m
> ```

```
    #import "GesturesViewController.h"
#import "GesturesAppDelegate.h"

@implementation GesturesViewController

@synthesize imageView;


CGRect originalFrame,fullScreenFrame;

BOOL isFullScreenMode;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Loading test image
        imageView.image = [UIImage   imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"];
    //---tap gesture---
    isFullScreenMode = NO;

    originalFrame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x,imageView.frame.origin.y,imageView.frame.size.width,imageView.frame.size.height);


    //changes
    fullScreenFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,768,1004);
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];

    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];

    //---pinch gesture---
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = 
    [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
    [pinchGesture release];   

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

//---handle tap gesture---
-(IBAction) handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    // HOW TO ACCOMPLISH THIS PART
    if (isFullScreenMode)
        [imageView setFrame:originalFrame];
    else
        [imageView setFrame:fullScreenFrame];

    [imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
    isFullScreenMode = !isFullScreenMode;
    NSLog(@"Image View : %@",imageView);
}

//---handle pinch gesture---
-(IBAction) handlePinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender { 
    CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) sender scale];   

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        // HOW TO ACCOMPLISH THIS ---
        if (factor > 1 && !isFullScreenMode) {
            //---pinching in---
            [imageView setFrame:fullScreenFrame];

        } else {
            //---pinching out---
            [imageView setFrame:originalFrame];

        } 
        isFullScreenMode = !isFullScreenMode;
        [imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
    }   
    NSLog(@"Image View : %@",imageView);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [images release];
    [imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)toggleZoom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (proxyView)
    {
        CGRect frame =
            [proxyView.superview
                convertRect:self.view.frame
                fromView:self.view.window];
        self.view.frame = frame;

        CGRect proxyViewFrame = proxyView.frame;

        [proxyView.superview addSubview:self.view];
        [proxyView removeFromSuperview];
        [proxyView autorelease];
        proxyView = nil;
        self.view.frame = proxyViewFrame;

    }
    else
    {
        proxyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        proxyView.hidden = YES;
        proxyView.autoresizingMask = self.view.autoresizingMask;
        [self.view.superview addSubview:proxyView];

        CGRect frame =
            [self.view.window
                convertRect:self.view.frame
                fromView:proxyView.superview];
        [self.view.window addSubview:self.view];
        self.view.frame = frame;
        self.view.frame = self.view.window.bounds;

    }


}
```

I have selected only necessary portion of the code...... its from `ZoomingViewController`....
If you see its same as we have discussed earlier..... but with few improvements.......

Comment: Ok thank you very much. can you please integrate it with my code, so i can see the whole code in one place instead of many places. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you have to first store your original frame size somewhere globally so that you can reassing it later on.

```
you need create two global frames

    CGRect originalFrame, fullScreenFrame;

    //in viewDidLoad initialize these frames... originalFrame with imageView frame and 
fullScreenFrame with the iPad window coordinates........ but remeber this can distort the
 aspect ratio so just calculate the aspect ratio of original image by using its height and
 width and accordingly create the full screen frame for the image....... 

    and just assign these frames in your gesture action.
```

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, but a sample of code will be more explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
viewDidLoad
originalFrame = imageView.frame;
```

or

```
originalFrame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x,imageView.frame.origin.y,imageView.frame.size.width,imageView.frame.size.height);
```

appDelegate <----- get the instance of your appdelegate object so that we can retrieve the window object.......

```
UIWindow *tempWindow = [appDelegate window];
fullScreenFrame = CGRectMake(tempWindow .frame.origin.x,tempWindow .frame.origin.y,tempWindow .frame.size.width,tempWindow.frame.size.height);
```

//****in event just set frame of the imageView-- for knowing the current state-- whether its fullScreen or original frame we need to have a flag........it should be global...
so declare a global flag ....`BOOL isFullScreenMode`  and initialize it as `NO` in

```
viewDidLoad
isFullScreenMode = NO;
```

in gesture actions just check this flag and write  following...

```
if (isFullScreenMode)
        [imageView setFrame:originalFrame];
else
       [imageView setFrame:fullScreenFrame];

isFullScreenMode = !isFullScreenMode;
```

Comment: Seems intresting, can you please put all this in one piece so i can test it, cause i don't know where to put all this lines on my codes. Thanks.

Comment: please paste me your viewcontroller's .h and .m so that I can make changes in it..... thanks

Comment: please suggest some image that I can use for testing...thanks

Comment: Sorry, you can test with this image : [http://img685.imageshack.us/i/architecturek.jpg/]. you'll see that there are some problems. Many THANKS.

Comment: Sorry, But from my network I am unable to access this image(proxy).....could you please share some general link

Comment: Sorry, use this istead : [http://storage.canalblog.com/96/97/676123/46712975.jpg] it's a random picture from google images :).

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation ImageFullScreen
@synthesize myImage;

#import "GesturesViewController.h"
#import "GesturesAppDelegate.h"

@implementation GesturesViewController

@synthesize imageView;

CGRect originalFrame,fullScreenFrame;

BOOL isFullScreenMode;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Loading test image
    imageView.image = [UIImage   imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"];
    //---tap gesture---
    isFullScreenMode = NO;

    originalFrame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x,imageView.frame.origin.y,imageView.frame.size.width,imageView.frame.size.height);


    //changes
    fullScreenFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,768,1004);
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];

    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];

    //---pinch gesture---
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = 
    [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
    [pinchGesture release];   

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

//---handle tap gesture---
-(IBAction) handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    // HOW TO ACCOMPLISH THIS PART
    if (isFullScreenMode)
        [imageView setFrame:originalFrame];
    else
        [imageView setFrame:fullScreenFrame];

    [imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
    isFullScreenMode = !isFullScreenMode;
    NSLog(@"Image View : %@",imageView);
}

//---handle pinch gesture---
-(IBAction) handlePinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender { 
    CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) sender scale];   

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        // HOW TO ACCOMPLISH THIS ---
        if (factor > 1 && !isFullScreenMode) {
            //---pinching in---
            [imageView setFrame:fullScreenFrame];

        } else {
            //---pinching out---
            [imageView setFrame:originalFrame];

        } 
        isFullScreenMode = !isFullScreenMode;
        [imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
    }   
    NSLog(@"Image View : %@",imageView);
}
```

Comment: Thanks what you mean by get an instance of appdelegate? do you mean ImageFullScreenAppDelegate? i'm not sure i can do this!

Comment: see above updated code....... if any syntax related issue comes just correct it.... thanks

Comment: Thanks for this code, but when i run it it does not display the image on full screen mode! you can test it with any image. Thanks again.

Comment: i think window frame is not reflecting correcly........  just change the fullScreenFrame with suitable origin and size... thanks

Comment: Thanks, i think we have a problem with fullScreenFrame (it not reflect the full screen on an ipad!)

Comment: we can then use two frames .... for landscapeOrientation and portrait one....... these frames could have hard coded values ..... CGRectMake(0,0,748,1024) and CGRectMake(0,0,1004,768)... thanks

Comment: Ok, i added this line to my code : `fullScreenFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);` but i got no full screen you can see the result before and after at this links : [http://img855.imageshack.us/i/beforen.png/] and [http://img193.imageshack.us/i/aftery.png/]

Comment: did that worked? also one thing i forget to mention you need some aspect ratio calculation code for image sizing so image view does not distort on fullScreenMOde....... one more thing make sure your fullScreenFrame should have width and height greater than the originalFrame.......... else changes wouldn't reflect. thanks

Comment: You see my previous comment with images before and after?

Comment: hey you are in portrait mode.... for this you need fullScreenFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,748,1024);...........

Comment: You can see the result here:http://img857.imageshack.us/i/portraitmode.png/[]. Thanks.

Comment: I think there is some problem with the "center/frame" of the imageView itself.......... you should print(nslog) imageView object in gesture methods........ so that we can get the frame parameters..... do it at the last line of the methos.... so that we get changes correctly........ thanks

Comment: NSLog("Image View : %@",imageView);............ this will print all the things that we need.......... also as per over current code image will be distorted.....(because of aspect ratio)..... but here we are jsut trying to make the image frame start with origin (0,0)......

Comment: Thanks, all this seems good to my problem, but still have the problem of centring image also, when image is in full screen i lost a lot of image details!! is this normal? thanks.

Comment: It all depends upon the image resolution. If you strech image more than its original resolution it will lost its details.... my code is working correctly without centering problem.... you can set center for imageView using ..... [imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(specify center coordinates here)]

Comment: Thanks for all this advices. My question how can i deal with resolution problem? Thanks.

Comment: We can maintain aspect ratio,to show image properly(but it may distort if it grows more than its actual resolution), but we can not increase resolution of an image... since it is image's inherent property. .... one thing we can do is to use images with atleast 768*1024 resolution..... but not sure whether you have this choice or not?

Comment: Ok, how we can maintain aspect ratio. Thanks.

Comment: here maintaing aspectRatio would be based on originalFrame. you will just need to have " float aspectRatio" that will hold the width/height ratio..... and using this you will have to create fullScreenFrame's width and height(keep one thing constant and calculate other)...... suppose width = 768(taking it as constant) then height = width/aspectRatio......... and you can do same for the other case...

Comment: Is this normal : `UIImage *sourceImage = imageView.image;
    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
    NSLog(@"Widhth : %@", width);
    NSLog(@"Height : %@", height);` This output null?

Comment: I didn't understand the solution of aspect ratio! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, i posted my code(the code i'm testing), so you can see it and tell me what's wrong with it, cause it seems that it do nothing!!! i don't know where to put : 1024 and 768 on the code because you are using height and width? Thanks.

Comment: what are the dimension of you actual image?........ n do you really want to scale it up fully only upto the iPad screen.... or if it has greater size than to its original.... here in my code its giving me desired result

Comment: The size of the image normally don't exceed the size of the ipad, and i want just to put it on full screen, for example, if my image is : 500x400, i want to display it 1024x768. Where to put the dimensions of full screen? cause i see anything in the code that refer to this. Thanks.

Comment: fullScreenFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,768,1004); ..... for portrait....     fullScreenFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,748); ..... for landscap.... in viewDidLoad of your class.... where we have written...... fullScreenFrame = CGRectMake(self.view .frame.origin.x,self.view .frame.origin.y,self.view .frame.size.width,height);...... we were actually trying to use self.view's dimensions for this purpose but you can use hardcoded if you wish....
    Thanks

Comment: Sorry i want to use hardcoded values, because actually the code does anything?! is it normal? can you please modify my code, so i can see the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Really thanks for all your effort, but it seems that it is a hard task to accomplish, in this link he did the same thing but with another approach : [http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/zoomingviewcontroller-to-animate-uiview.html]. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have any ideas, on how to the same thing as in the link? thanks.